# How to add unordered list - circle or square it doesn´t work...what´ wrong?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have made this home page - I tried to style the list but it doesn´t work - I just want to add a circle on each row (unordered list) http://ctrlv.cz/a6ib

The website is ucetnictvi-ut.cz

Comment: web is on ucetnictvi-it.cz

Answer (score 0):

your website link is not working. It shows a blank page.

anyway, you can try this for any unordered list.

html code:

```
<ul>
 <li>Item 1</li>
 <li>Item 2</li>
 <li>Item 3</li>
 <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS code:

```
ul{list-style-type:disc;list-style-position: outside;}
ul li{margin-left:20px;}
```

Hopefully this will work.

Comment: hi sorry the site is there ucetnictvi-it.cz but the pblem is even if I put this code, it doesn´t show a circle  <ul>
 <li style="list-style-type: disc;>Item 1</li>
 <li style="list-style-type: disc;>Item 2</li>
 <li style="list-style-type: disc;>Item 3</li>
 <li style="list-style-type: disc;>Item 4</li>
</ul>

Comment: I think your problem is here:

<li style="list-style-type:disc;>

It should be :

<li style="list-style-type:disc;">

A semicolon is missed here.

Try this

Comment: And try to avoid inline styling.